# Create set when several occurences in row of array

Tags: python, arrays, set

I have an array A of which I want to get the first part of an item's name (which is stored in column 0) if there is a certain number of 'na's in that row and then store that first part of the name (before the ' - ') in a set.

My code works if I look for only one 'na' in a row. But I don't know how to adjust it to e.g. >2 'na's.  I tried to do it with the .count() function but then I get the error message that I can't use it in arrays.

```
    todelete = set(row[0].split(" - ", 1)[1] for row in A[0:] if 'na' in row)
```

My input A has the same form as the following example and I would like to store the string 'BCDE' in my set.

```
    A = (['A - BCDE', '3413', '4354', '6655', '6573', '7523', 'na'],
         ['A - CDEF', '7663', '5332', '2364', '1263', '3234', '4343'],
         ['B - BCDE', 'na', 'na', '3443', 'na', '4153', '1223'],
         ['B - CDEF', '3456', '8756', '3456', '2345', '3456', '1234'])
```

Comment: post some input examples please. i.e various examples for `A` var.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all values in `A` are strings:

```
set(row[0].split(" - ", 1)[1] for row in A[0:]
    if len(filter(lambda item: 'na' in item, row)) > 2)
```

If only exact value of `'na'` `A` are needed:

```
set(row[0].split(" - ", 1)[1] for row in A[0:]
    if len(filter(lambda item: 'na' == item, row)) > 2)
```

This example:

```
A = (['A - BCDE', '3413', '4354', '6655', '6573', '7523', 'na'],
     ['A - CDEF', '7663', '5332', '2364', '1263', '3234', '4343'],
     ['B - BCDE', 'na', 'na', '3443', 'na', '4153', '1223'],
     ['B - CDEF', '3456', '8756', '3456', '2345', '3456', '1234'])
```

Would output the set:

```
{'BCDE'}
```

If the row values are not restricted to strings, a type check in the filter function is required:

```
set(row[0].split(" - ", 1)[1] for row in A[0:]
    if len(filter(lambda item: isinstance(item, str) and 'na' in item, row)) > 2)
```

Comment: I set all values in A strings and then your method works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your problem is actually how to count occurrences of `'na'` in a numpy array. There is not a function for that but it's easy to write one:

```
def count(a, v):
    return a[a == v].size
```

then:

```
todelete = set(row[0].split(" - ", 1)[1] for row in A[0:] if count(row, 'na') > 2)
```